# M2: How to change URL after switch language

Tags: magento2, switcher

I want to change end URL after switch language

from:
[image]

to

domainname.com **/pl/**

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set below configuration to yes

**Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls > Yes**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable store codes from admin

```
Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options > Add Store Code to Urls > No
```

and then run in terminal

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```